# Changing the font in the ToC?

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents

I am using the package `memoir` and I redefined the fonts related to the chapters headings:

```
\renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\Large\sffamily\scshape\raggedleft\so} 
\renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\huge\sffamily\bfseries\scshape\color{darkBlue}}
```

But altough I am using a sans-serif font for the chapters, the ToC use a serif version of LM. That's not a major problem except that I have this warning:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/lmss/bx/sc' undefined
```

So Latex is complaining that it can't find a small-caps and bold version of LM sans-serif.

[image]

And the table of content:

[image]

So I am a bit confused:

- My chapters appear as I want (sans serif font)
- The ToC looks like it is using serifed fonts
- Yet it is complaining not to find a SS font
- I have this strange problem with `viii`
- LM SS seems to have a SC bold version: [Latex font catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/latinmodernsans/)

It seems that I don't know enough about Latex and fonts ...

Comment: Very nice chapter headings by the way. What do you use for that?

Comment: It's one of the available style in `memoir`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LaTeX tells you that it is find a font. It also tells you which font it uses instead:

```
 LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/lmss/bx/sc' undefined
 (Font)              using `T1/lmss/bx/n' instead on input line 8.
```

Substituations are normal. As you can see here a sans serif font is used as substitute.

\chapnamefont defines the font of the vertical chapter beside the large "2" not the font in the toc.

For the problem with "viii": http://texfaq.org/FAQ-tocloft

Answer (score 14):

The commands for the TOC entries are different to the commands for the headings. To get sans serif fonts in the TOC, redefine the `\cftXfont` commands, where X stands for chapter, section etc.

This will achieve sans serif chapter and section entries in the TOC:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont\sffamily}   
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont\sffamily}
```

Comment: For whatever reason, I get a `\cftsectionfont undefined` error when using `\renewcommand{\cftsectionfont}{\normalfont\sffamily} `. If I change `\cftsectionfont` to `\cftsecfont`, everything works as intended.

Answer (score 3):

To make the TOC sans serif, just add the command `\textsf`, like this: 
`\textsf{\tableofcontents}}`

Comment: The font might be reset inside `\tableofcontents` by memoir. Anyway, I would recommend to use {\sffamily\tableofcontents}` instead.

Comment: @MartinScharrer @Andre Using either `\textsf{\tableofcontents}` or `\sffamily\tableofcontents` makes the entries sans serif but NOT the page numbers. Any solution for this?

Comment: @Dominik ```\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
{\sffamily \maketitle
\tableofcontents}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}``` will do.