# Changing the font of the numbers in the ToC in the memoir class

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, memoir

I found these rows of code in [this thread:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5905/changing-the-font-in-the-toc/5914#5914)

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont\sffamily}   
\renewcommand{\cftsectionfont}{\normalfont\sffamily}
```

which changes the font for the listings but not for the numbers. Are there a different set of commands for doing that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Page 164 of the memoir manual provides the answer:

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont\sffamily}   
\renewcommand{\cftsectionpagefont}{\normalfont\sffamily}
```

Comment: I can't believe it. I have read those pages over and over again but for some reason I can't seem to understand the content of them... :(